# Java poi returns CELL_TYPE_BLANC on not empty cell

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

hy guys.

i'm using java poi to parse excel. it worked fine till this moment. i have xls file. there is a cell (R1885C4) in it. it has string inside. if i select it in the top bar excel shows me its value. but when i'm parsing this file poi says that its CELL_TYPE is 3 which is CELL_TYPE_BLANC. so i got empty string.

i tried to extract string with:

```
cell.getStringCellValue();
cell.toString();
row.getCell(colNumber,Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).toString();
```

but i failed. it always returns empty string as value of this cell.

can anybody help me to solve this problem.

any help appriciated!

Comment: Since the rest of your parsing is working, and CELL_TYPE_BLANK works elsewhere, we would need more details.  Can you extract just part of your spreadsheet that shows the problem (maybe the row, or the column, or possibly just R1885C4) and link it?

Comment: well, i've done a screen. it's here https://pp.vk.me/c604831/v604831002/4741/D752_RCG-ec.jpg. the selected cell "ЛЕГКОВЫЕ ЗИМА" is the cell with CELL_TYPE_BLANK

Comment: That screen shot will not allow anyone to reproduce the problem, though.

You have no problem with R9C4 (the only other cell I see on the screen that starts with Cyrillic characters)?

Comment: there are many cells with cyrillic symbols. poi extracts their values well. the problem is with this cpecific cell! i cut the xls file so it was smaller and easier to work. this is the link https://psv4.vk.me/c810428/u15983002/docs/571c6a1652a8/PRICE.xls. after i cut it now the target cell address is R38C4.

Comment: Can you re-upload, the link does not work for me...

Comment: yeap. new link http://best-shina.zp.ua/frontend/files/PRICE.xls

Comment: I could not reproduce.  With your spreadsheet PRICE.xls, and using POI version 3.10 (because I already had it downloaded), I get data out of R38C4 just with:

 `Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

 Row r = sheet.getRow(37);

 Cell c = r.getCell(3);

 String value = c.getStringCellValue();
System.out.println(value)`